# Using a hard coded value and sub query in an IN clause

Tags: sql, db2, dbvisualizer

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent.Table
WHERE Ref_Num IN ('4205' or (SELECT Ref_Num FROM Child.Table WHERE Ref_Num ='234'))
AND Asset_Type IN ('PUMPS','COLL')
```

This query doesn't work. The subquery returns 53 rows, instead of typing out all the children ref numbers is there a way to put them in the query along with the parent number of '4205'.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `UNION` like `SELECT 4205 UNION ALL /*Your Query*/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM Parent.Table
  WHERE Ref_Num In (SELECT Ref_Num
                      FROM Child.Table
                      WHERE Ref_Num ='234'
                    UNION
                      SELECT '4205' As Ref_Num
                        FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
    AND Asset_Type IN ('PUMPS','COLL')
```

Note that SYSDUMMY1 is an EBCDIC table. If you need ASCII, use SYSDUMMYA. If you need Unicode, use SYSDUMMYU.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Given that he's not using the value contained in the dummy table, does it matter what the encoding of the field is?  Or does the optimizer auto-convert if you reference the table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a union query

```
 select 4205 ref_num
 from some_small_table
 union
 select ref_num
 from child.table
 etc
```

Comment: This doesn't work as a filter to only return the records with the ref numbers I want. It just adds to the returned rows.